# Remember me no longer works in Symfony 5 after transferring to keeping session in DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I created sessions within the DB, and that seems to be working well. The DB sessions followed this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/database.html

Now the remember me function ceases to function, so now I viewed this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#remember-me-token-in-database

I attempted to implement this, but it doesn't seem to be working. The Database is empty when ever I log in and use the remember me function.

This is how my services.yaml file looks like:

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    app.profile_picture: '%kernel.project_dir%/%env(uploadPath)%/profiles/'
    app.projects: '%kernel.project_dir%/%env(uploadPath)%/projects/'
    app.stripe_secret_key: '%env(stripe_secret_key)%'
    app.stripe_connect_id: '%env(stripe_connect_id)%'
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            $profilePicture: '%app.profile_picture%'
            $stripeSecretKey: '%app.stripe_secret_key%'
            $stripeConnectId: '%app.stripe_connect_id%'
            $projects: '%app.projects%'

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
    Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\RememberMe\DoctrineTokenProvider: ~
    app.custom.limiter:
        class: App\Limiter\CustomLimiter
        arguments:
            - '@limiter.max_login_failure'
```

Security.yaml:

```
remember_me:
        secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
        path:     /
        token_provider: 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\RememberMe\DoctrineTokenProvider'
```

Doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        override_url: true
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        schema_filter: ~^(?!rememberme_token)~

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to associate the database session with the remember tokens in the DB too? Not sure what I'm missing, but remember me still isn't working after all of this.

Answer (score 0):

The most common pitfall when implementing "remember me" in Symfony is to render the `_remember_me` field in a Symfony form without setting its block prefix to an empty string.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ConnectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...

        $builder
            ->add('_remember_me', Type\CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Trust this device',
                'required' => false,
            ]);
    }
}
```

The generated `_remember_me` field name will be `connect__remember_me` in HTML because the block prefix of the `ConnectType` is `connect` (look at the `getBlockPrefix` method of the `Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType` class).

As Symfony looks for a posted `_remember_me` property, you need to set your block prefix to an empty string:

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return '';
}
```

Comment: So this isn't the case - I looked but the _remember_me checkbox has no prefix. Are there other common pitfalls I should look out for?

Comment: Well I just implemented it [in this PR](https://github.com/minutis-redcall/app/pull/593) to see if I had your error, but everything seems working fine. Maybe the PR code will help you dig your own issue.

Comment: Well it's interesting because I just turned off DB sessions and the remember me function works fine, but the moment I have it turned on, it seems to cease to function.

Comment: I'lll look into this more. Thanks.